# JavaScript function not giving the correct output

Tags: javascript

I have the following function.

```
function checkWinner (results)
{ 
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
  if (results[i] > 50)
  {
    var win = results[i];
    return win;
  }
  else if  (results[i] < 50)
  {
    var win = 0;
    return win;
  }
}
```

the results array is:

```
var results = [12,32,53,12,23];
```

However i get the out 0 when i am expecting 53.

i am calling the function using:

```
var win = (checkWinner(results));
```

When i delete the else if statement from the code, then i get the correct answer of 53. So i assume i am doing something wrong there. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you are actually **only** comparing the **first** value of the array. You immediately return from the function in the first iteration of the loop (if the value is not 50).

Comment: What are you actually trying to check? That the array contains any number greater than 50? What array element is greater than 50? What if there are multiple array elements > 50? Some context here would be great.

Comment: While it'd be easy for someone to fix the problem for you, it would be much more beneficial for you to learn how to walk through the code using a debugger and figure it out for yourself. Try http://getfirebug.com/, once you installed it, there is a debugger available in the "Script" tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function always returns from the "for" loop on the first iteration in which the value is not 50. Think about it: your "if" condition will return from the function when the value is greater than 50, and also when it's less than 50.  With your test data, the first element of the array is less than 50, so you get zero.

Since you've already discovered that removing the "else" portion fixes the problem, what more do you need?

Comment: Ah yes ok i see the mistake. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

If you step through your code either in a debugger or on paper the bug should become clear.

Basically the very first element in the array is causing the else clause to be executed, and in that clause you return right away. So the function is only examining the very first element.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if someone has 50 as result ??.. the secode should be an else and not else if

Main this happens because you explicitly return 0.

```
function checkWinner (results)
{ 
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
  {
    if (results[i] > 50)
    {
      return results[i];
    }
    else
    {
      return results[i];
    }
  }
}
```